# What does "svc power stayon wireless" do?

Tags: shell

Looking at the reference to `svc` on my phone there are options for `svc power stayon [true|false|usb|ac|wireless]`. I'm curious what `usb`, `ac`, and `wireless` do when you use them?

I tried `svc power stayon wireless` and it seemed the command succeeded, but I don't know what it did, or how to revert it.

I'm on an LG Tribute if that helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Executing `svc power` on the shell will bring the usage:

```
usage: svc power stayon [true|false|usb|ac|wireless]
         Set the 'keep awake while plugged in' setting.
```

The command will set whether to keep your device awake (prevent sleeping) or not while it's being charged on specific platform: USB charging, AC power, wireless charging, or all of them:

- `true` will set all flags (`usb`, `ac`, `wireless`)
- `false` will clear all flags
- `usb`/`ac`/`wireless` will set that specific flag while clear the other

The same setting usually can be accessed on "Developer options" named "Stay awake", though it's simpler with only toggle to turn on/off.

<sup>Reference: [source code of `com.android.commands.svc.PowerCommand`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/cmds/svc/src/com/android/commands/svc/PowerCommand.java#46)</sup>

Comment: Is this setting permanent or will get reset when I reboot the device.

Comment: @darth_coder I haven't tested the reboot, but I believe it persists. Let me know if it's otherwise...

Comment: also will this disable screen lock until the device is flashed.

Comment: Does this persist after reboot?