# Android 5.1 prevent USB Ethernet interface to go into sleep/suspend in AC loss (PM)

Tags: battery-life

We are using MT8163 based Android device which is connected with TP-link based USB-Ethernet device over MT8163 USB host.  Our requirement is to prevent the TP-link USB-Ethernet dongle to enter sleep mode and keep it available without suspending in case the MT8163 loses AC power. What are the changes w.r.t Android or AOSP to achieve this functionality

Thanks,
Sai

Comment: When the CPU looses power usually the USB controller looses power, too. The USB controller powers the USB-Ethernet device and without power an USB-Ethernet device is unable to work (well-known in applied electrical engineering). Have you tried to place an active powered USB hub between USB-Ethernet device and the Android device?

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/109955

Comment: Thanks for reply Robert, the MT8163 has battery power(in case loss of AC) and the MT8163 is providing the power/controlling the USB-ethernet device. Our intention is to keep the USB controller, USB-Ethernet device to stay powered and work even the MT8163 goes to aSleep mode(savor mode not low power mode). Like giving exception or wakelock to USB subsystem. Rest of the interfaces(wifi, LCD etc..) can go to sleep mode to conserve the power. USB hub is not possible keep in system as per design limitation.